# Application History is not getting generated in formsflow.ai

Tags: bpmn, camunda, formsflow.ai, formsflow

I am using Opensource [formsflow.ai](https://formsflow.ai) version [v4.0.2](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/releases/tag/v4.0.2). This is the Repo [Link](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai). I could get the Repo up and Running using docker deployment [as instructed](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai-dev/blob/develop/deployment/docker/README.md).

I had created a form and BPMN workflow for a specific use-case in formsflow.ai. The BPMN workflow is similar to the examples provided in the formsflow.ai opensource. This workflow consists of 4 statuses eg: New, Approved, Rejected, and Completed as shown Below. But when I am submitting the application from the client the application history is not getting created.

[image: My Custom Workflow]

I am not sure what went wrong here, can anyone please help me with a solution. Could see the sample workflows they provided created history but not my custom Workflow.

Comment: Could you post the listeners you use in the bpmn workflow here??

Comment: I have added the following listeners: BPMFormDataPipelineListener, NotifyListener, and FormConnectorListener.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use Application Audit Listener as mentioned in the document [here](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai/blob/master/forms-flow-bpm/starter-examples/listeners/applicationaudit-readme.md).

> org.camunda.bpm.extension.hooks.listeners.ApplicationAuditListener
> This component can be used on any event of task or execution. Upon configuration, this send value from cam variables: "applicationStatus" and "formUrl" to formsflow.ai system for capturing audit.

Comment: Thanks, I missed it. Worked like a charm :)

Comment: What is the point of writing an additional audit trail when the embedded process engine already does so ootb? And if so, why not use a generic hook and instead manually register listeners per task?

Comment: @rob2universe in formsflow.ai there is a separate audit maintained based on the custom status as mentioned by the post owner. This audit is maintained on a separate component and displayed that during each action/stage.  The problem with the generic hook is that the audit is generated newly each time, the parameters get changes from the workflow based on actions, so to capture that we cannot use generic hook.

Comment: The onTaskEvent hook triggers on any state change of a task, without explicit registration of a listener.